# VS code CSS showing weird behavior while using live-server

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

**HTML h1 h2 tag, the default margin, padding all gone**. All the default behavior of Css is gone while I am using live-server or the node-js live server for some reason.
sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Rubik:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Omnifood Hero Section</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div>Logo</div>
        <div>Navigation</div>
        <h1>hey</h1>
      </nav>

      <div>
        <h1>A healthy meal delivered to your door,every single day</h1>
        <p>
          The smart 365-days-per-year food subscription that will make you eat
          healty agian. Tailored to your personal tastes and nutritonal need
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Start eating well</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section>
      <h2>Some random heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

In CSS only write this

```
    * {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
   }
```

Here's a screenshot
[using live-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QvtG.png)

Comment: Hi! When running your code i get regular browser default style margins etc. Maybe live-server automatically adds some reset stylesheet without you knowing? Please check the actual delivered html/css using the source-code and/or devtool feature of your browser.

Comment: yes, I think live-server is somehow resetting the stylesheet cause opening without live-server is working fine.